# Updating MySQL table in Java

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, jdbc, addition

I have updated the code and now the only error I am getting is a syntax error which I'm unsure how to resolve :

```
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try 
            {
                st = con.createStatement();     
                String searchQuery = "INSERT INTO user (user_id, genre_id, hair_length, " + "user_fname, user_lname, user_age, user_gender) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
               (PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(searchQuery))
               {         
                   insert.setString(1, userText.getText());
                   insert.setString(2, genreText.getText());
                   innsert.setString(3, hairText.getText());
                   insert.setString(4, firstText.getText());
                   insert.setString(6, ageText.getText());
                   insert.setString(7, genderText.getText());
                   insert.executeUpdate(searchQuery);
               }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Added To MySQL");             
                }
            catch (SQLException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
```

[Eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKxQX.jpg)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGrR8.jpg)

Comment: where is your gui class? paste relevant code? what's the exact error? On which line is compiler complaining about the same?

Comment: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any Syntax error like your case, or SQL Injection you have to use PreparedStatement, for example :

```
String searchQuery = "INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `genre_id`, `hair_length`, "
            + "`user_fname`,`user_lname`,`user_age`,`user_gender`) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(searchQuery)) {
    insert.setString(1, userText.getText());
    insert.setString(2, genreText.getText());
    ...
    insert.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Added To MySQL");
}
```

---

You are missing `'` in your query :

```
+ "', '" + hairText.getText() + "','" +
//----^--------------------------^
```

and :

```
+ "','" + genderText.getText() + "' )";
//---^----------------------------^
```

---

**Edit**

Ok you have a small problem in your code, use this instead :

```
JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String searchQuery = "INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `genre_id`, `hair_length`, "
                + "`user_fname`,`user_lname`,`user_age`,`user_gender`) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try (PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(searchQuery)) {
            insert.setString(1, userText.getText());
            insert.setString(2, genreText.getText());
            insert.setString(3, hairText.getText());
            insert.setString(4, firstText.getText());
            insert.setString(5, surText.getText());
            insert.setString(6, ageText.getText());
            insert.setString(7, genderText.getText());
            insert.executeUpdate(searchQuery);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Added To MySQL");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok so this works much better thanks! The only syntax error i'm getting now is at the end of :

    String searchQuery = "INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `genre_id`,           
    `hair_length`,`user_fname`,`user_lname`,`user_age`,`user_gender`) 
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Syntax Error on token ";" , try expected after this token

Comment: @NeilDavies your query should look like this `String searchQuery = "INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `genre_id`, `hair_length`, "
            + "`user_fname`,`user_lname`,`user_age`,`user_gender`) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";`

Comment: that is how i have written it but I am still getting a syntax error at the end of the query just on the  ;
 Syntax error on token ";", try expected after  this token

Comment: String searchQuery = "INSERT INTO user (user_id, genre_id, 
    hair_length, " + "user_fname,user_lname,user_age,user_gender) " + 
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Comment: I am relatively new to stack overflow so don't have access to chat yet

Comment: are you sure @NeilDavies can you take a screen shot of your ide and edit your question please ?

Comment: ok @NeilDavies i edit my answer you have mixed your statement thats all, try this and let me know

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much :) next stop updating the table in the JFrame!

Comment: sorry to bother you again - upon this action being performed no rows are added to the table or db it just shows the dialogue box I was wondering if there was anything else missing

Comment: yes @ndvs92 maybe you miss `insert.executeUpdate(searchQuery);` like i do check my edit ;)

Comment: move to a MySQL Error now! Progress :)

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

guessing this is because it doesnt follow my SQL command so have to match it up?

Comment: what type of `user_id` is it auto_increment @ndvs92?

Comment: user_id not null auto_increment

Comment: ok so I take the user_id out of the code, the genre_id im assuming the same? As that is an FK in the user table but again same data type and in the genre table is also not null auto_increment.

New SQL Error is: Parameter index out of range (7 > number of parameters, which is 6). @YCF_L

Comment: you don't remove the `?` you have to make the same number

Comment: yes so if there is 6 columns being queried then there must be `?` x 6? @YCF_L

Comment: yes @ndvs92 you have to learn the link that i already mention in answer